# Related area of someone's job

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word/expression that refers to the related area of someone's job.

I've thinking in `industry`, `job field` or `work field` but I am not sure which one is more correct or if there is another different word that fits better.

Imagine the following sentence:

> They both share the same _____

How would you fill the empty slot?

There are other sentences where `industry` sounds good to me. For instance:

> I don't like that family, they all work on the computer industry.

`Cars industry` also sounds good, but what about `laws industry`? That sounds weird.

So, is there a more general word? Can someone tell me a solution for each of these cases?

Comment: `Area of expertise` may fits fine in the first example also, but I am still confused with the examples below. What about a nurse and a doctor, they both work on health ____?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @JonLarby, the word *industry* does work in most situations.

> - They work in the **legal industry**.
> - They work in the **health industry**.

Also, the word **sector** could be used to replace the word *industry* in situations where it "sounds weird"*. Although the word *sector* is often associated with economics, it is also commonly used to describe all fields/professions. [(See here)](http://www.totalprofessions.com/profession-finder/sector-summaries)

*this could be because the word *industry* is mostly associated with *manufacturing* and *production*, which makes it sound odd when used to describe professions such as law and health, which are based on human services rather than the production of goods.

> [**Sector (def):**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sector)
>   one of the areas into which the economic activity of a country is divided.
>
> - *They both work in the **health sector***.
> - *They both work in the **legal sector***.

Answer (score 0):

I think *industry* is the word you are looking for in most of your examples. For situations like law, medicine, etc., where the focus is on the individual's skills, rather than the use the skills are being put to, then [profession](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/profession) is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, `industry` work on some cases. But `profession` is a more specific word, that usually mean they have the same job or studied the same. For instance, a nurse and a doctor, they don't have the same job and they didn't study the same. They work on the `health industry`? Sounds weird again.

Comment: @MartínDelaFuente I would say doctors and nurses both work in the medical profession, where the focus is on patient care. People who work for companies manufacturing drugs or medical exquipment work in the health industry. To me, profession alludes to the vocational aspect of one's work, where as industry refers to the commercialisation of it.